# How to join multi URL output in curl to pass to jq

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I am using a multi-url curl command like this:

`curl -snL http://url1 http://url2`

Each produces json as such:

```
{
   "thing": 1,
   "other": "foo"
}

{
   "thing": 2,
   "other": "baz"
}
```

what I want to know is if there is a simple way to combine these so they can effectively be passed to jq (or maybe jq can just do this) such that I get:

```
[{
   "thing": 1,
   "other": "foo"
},
{
   "thing": 2,
   "other": "baz"
}]
```

and thus can do, ultimately: `curl -snL http://url1 http://url2 | jq -re .[].other`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQ accepts a stream of JSON. You don't have to do anything special to get it to read the data.

```
$ jq '.' test.json
{
  "thing": 1,
  "other": "foo"
}
{
  "thing": 2,
  "other": "baz"
}
$ jq -r '.other' test.json
foo
baz
```

Use `-s` if you want JQ to *slurp* the input into one big array.

```
$ jq -s '.' test.json
[
  {
    "thing": 1,
    "other": "foo"
  },
  {
    "thing": 2,
    "other": "baz"
  }
]
```

Comment: I remember `-s` now and that does the trick. The first one gives me indexing errors. Credit, you!